# ReactJS not rerendering after setState

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a simple ReactJS application that loads a list of users and shows a record for each user.

This is the component handling the loading of the users and showing them in a list, while the `UserCard` component will visualize the user information and allow for edits.

```
export default class UserManager extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        users:[]
    };
};

componentDidMount() {
    this.loadUsers();
};

loadUsers() {
    $.getJSON('/api/users').then((data) => {
        this.setState({ users: data.items });
    });
};

render() {
    return (
        <div className="animated fadeIn">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-sm-8 col-md-10">
                    <div id="userslist" className="userlist" >
                        {
                            this.state.users.map((user) => {
                                <UserCard user={user} />
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

I load the users on componentDidMount, and the api call returns successfully with all user data. The rendering of the users is however not triggered. The list will remain empty.

Am I missing something here? Do I have to trigger the rendering manually again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return the UserCard component from `map` body, if you don't return anything then, it will return `undefined` by default:

```
<div id="userslist" className="userlist" >
    {
        this.state.users.map((user) => {
            return  <UserCard user={user} />
        })
    }
</div>
```

Or write it like this without using `{}` because, you just want to return a component without any calculation or condition so `{}` is not required:

```
<div id="userslist" className="userlist" >
    {
        this.state.users.map((user,i) => <UserCard key={i} user={user} /> )
    }
</div>
```

Assign the unique `key` to each `UserCard`.

Comment: No this resolved my problem. Thanks for providing an explanation for this as wel!

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Mayank answer, you probably can do it without writing an explicit return statement, by using `()` instead of `{}` after the map function since it automatially returns the JSX inside it by default

```
        <div id="userslist" className="userlist" >
                    {
                        this.state.users.map((user) => (
                            <UserCard user={user} />
                        ))
                    }
                </div>
```